# How to find maven deprecated groupdIds

Tags: java, maven, gradle, dependency-management

I worked on a SpringBoot + GraphQL project and I noticed that artifact com.graphql-java:graphql-spring-boot-starter was unmaintained. No notice on the website, and plugins like versions-maven-plugin did not help me. After some searches on GitHub and Maven Central, I found this artifact moved from com.graphql-java to com.graphql-java-kickstart (the project has been forked and this is the new active maintainer).

Now, I am looking for good practices to find deprecated dependencies in Maven & Gradle projects. I downloaded the Maven Central index, extracted the full list of groupId+artifactIds, filtered it, and found some candidates (like bouncycastle that moved to org.bouncycastle).

> Q: I'd like to automatize detection of deprecated dependencies. Have you any advice for me? The naive solution would be to maintain a public list of deprecated dependencies (I did it for fun: [maven](https://github.com/jonathanlermitage/oga-maven-plugin) and [gradle](https://github.com/jonathanlermitage/oga-gradle-plugin) plugin), but I may miss something.

Thx,

Comment: It would be interesting to look for relocations (https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-relocation.html).

Comment: Some relocated projects don't use the `relocation` tag (like graphql-spring-boot-starter), but it's very interesting. I'll try to detect this tag in dependencies. Thx!